# How can I load AdBlock plus extension in selenium python permanently?

Tags: selenium

, It should not be installed freshly everytime I Invoke chromium session?

Even If it is installing the extention freshly, how can I make sure that it holds the previous settings.

Thanka in advance.

Comment: Have your tried something before asking here?

Comment: @Mukesh Whatever you do through selenium is for that driver instance only. I do not think, with the limited knowledge that I have, that you can add something permanently to a browser through selenium. There could be some other workaround, perhaps.

Comment: Thanks,
Even if we install a fresh Ad-Block extension everytime, is there any way by which we can modify the defaut filters to block cookie popus etc..

Comment: @Prophet, Yes. I did try the option for --loadExtension="adBlock" as chromeOptions, it use to instal AdBlock extension everytime and previous settings(applied filters) are reverted to default.